# VSCode Won't Break on Uncaught or Caught Exceptions When Using Attached Debugging

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used to be able to have Visual Studio Code break on caught and uncaught exceptions. The breakpoints are still marked, but it just won't break. Toggling normal breakpoints breaks the process fine, it's just that whenever I throw an error anywhere it doesn't break.

[image: Breakpoints are Checked]

Here is my launch.json:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name"                  : "Attach",
            "request"               : "attach",
            "type"                  : "node",
            "restart"               : true,
            "port"                  : 9229,
            "sourceMaps"            : true,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "remoteRoot"            : "/home/node/dist",
            "localRoot"             : "${workspaceFolder}/dist",
            "skipFiles"             : ["${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js", "<node_internals>/**/*.js"],
            "outFiles"              : ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/**.js"],
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using Docker and Node image "fermium-alpine",
OS X Big Sur 11.4.
VSCode 1.58.0.